# format a string with fill places

Tags: android

I have setup an edittext box and set the maxlength to 10. When I copy the edittext to a string myTitles. I need the myTiles to be 10 chars long and not dependent on what is entered in the edittext box.

```
      myTitles[0] = TitlesEdit.getText().toString();
```

The edittext was filled with ABCD so I need to add 6 spaces or placeholders after the ABCD. I have seen other post with str_pad and substr without success

```
        myTitles[0] = str_pad(strTest, 0, 10);
        myTitles[0] = substr(strTest,0, 10);
```

Comment: If you want a `string` with 10 chars you could do this : `String 10Chars = new String(new char[10])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
public static String newString(String str) {
    for (int i = str.length(); i <= 10; i++)
        str += "*";
    return str;
}
```

This will return a String with `*` replaced for the empty ones.

So, for eg, if your String is `abcde`, then on calling `newString()` as below

```
myTitles[0] = newString("abcde");
```

will return `abcde*****` as the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = new String("abcde");
for(int i=s.length();i<10;i++){
    s = s.concat("-");
}
```

Then output your string s.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lal, I use " " to fill and it worked fine. here is my new code.

```
                       String strTest = TitlesEdit.getText().toString();

                        for (int i = strTest.length(); i <= 10; i++) {
                            strTest += " ";
                        }

                        Log.d("TAG", "String" + strTest);
                        myTitles[intLinenumber] = strTest;
```